# what does eta constant mean in numpy

Tags: python, neural-network

I am using numpy to implement some neural network tutorials. There is a constant("eta") used in codes. What does it means and what it stands for?

Comment: eta is a greek letter $\eta$, it often is used for the learning rate. This is the distance with which you will reach to get to the next "more optimal" point when taking the gradient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually "eta" means learning rate, but it would be better if you could show an example.